# remove duplicates in multi array with different keys

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

i know that this question is answered more times here. but i can't figure out how to do this

i have an array with arrays in IT

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 37
            [4] => 41
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 74
            [2] => 80
            [3] => 82
            [4] => 94
            [5] => 95
            [6] => 100
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 94
        )

)
```

as you see in 4 and 15 keys we have duplicates (94 and 100)

i want to remove all this duplicates except one

so in final to have

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 37
            [4] => 41
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 74
            [2] => 80
            [3] => 82
            [4] => 94
            [5] => 95
            [6] => 100
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86
        )

)
```

Big thanks

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: as i say i tired more than 4-5 variants to do this. 

i create "stop_words" array and compare with my own array using foreach
i try to use serialize and array_unique functions - but its not work too couse keys are different

i dont ask for "free coding" no - i just want to know where to go to find solution about this problem.

Comment: They want you to show your way ... where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your outer array, inside loop over your inner arrays.

Check if the current value is already contained in a helper array, if so unset the array element (using the outer and inner level key.)

Then add the current value to the helper array, so that it can be recognized as a duplicate value when it occurs the next time.

```
$data = [
  11 => [3, 4, 5, 37, 41],
  4 => [67, 74, 80, 82, 94, 95, 100],
  15 => [86, 100, 94]
];

$helperArray = [];

foreach($data as $dkey => $item) {
    foreach($item as $ikey => $value) {
        if(in_array($value, $helperArray)) {
            unset($data[$dkey][$ikey]);
        }
        $helperArray[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Many thanks. i tired this way but always get an empty array like 

$array[11] => NULL
$array[4] => NULL
$array[15] => NULL

now I'll see what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most un-elegant solution but it will always do the trick...

```
<?php
/* Create the array */
$array[11][] = 3;
$array[11][] = 4;
$array[11][] = 5;
$array[11][] = 37;
$array[11][] = 41;
$array[4][] = 67;
$array[4][] = 74;
$array[4][] = 80;
$array[4][] = 82;
$array[4][] = 94;
$array[4][] = 95;
$array[4][] = 100;
$array[15][] = 86;
$array[15][] = 100;
$array[15][] = 94;

/* print the complete array : */
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '<pre>';

/* use a simple array to store values as you loop */
$A = [];
foreach($array as $key => $ar){
    
    foreach($ar as $k => $a){
        /* if the value already appeared somewhere... remove it from this and next locations...*/
        if(in_array($a,$A)){
            unset($array[$key][$k]);
        }
        $A[] = $a;

    }
}

/* Print our cleaned array. */
print_r($array);
```

will return:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 37
            [4] => 41
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 74
            [2] => 80
            [3] => 82
            [4] => 94
            [5] => 95
            [6] => 100
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 94
        )

)
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 37
            [4] => 41
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 74
            [2] => 80
            [3] => 82
            [4] => 94
            [5] => 95
            [6] => 100
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86
        )

)
```

Next time , please share your code, as bad as it can be or whatever it shows your way and that you have tried solving this for real...

Answer (score 0):

I made the data a bit more complex, so that the duplicates are not only in the array elements with the keys 4 and 15.

```
$data = [
  11 => [ 3, 4, 94, 5, 80, 37, 41 ],   // will be: 3, 4, 94, 5, 80, 37, 41
  4  => [ 67, 74, 80, 82, 95, 100 ],   // will be: 67, 74, 82, 95, 100 (80 > key 11)
  7  => [ 2, 4, 77, 81, 13, 100 ],     // will be: 2, 77, 81, 13 (4 > key 11, 100 > key 4) 
  15 => [ 86, 100, 94, 13 ]            // will be: 86 (100 > key 7, 94 > key 11, 13 > key 7)

];

$keys = array_reverse(array_keys($data));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
  $keyI = $keys[$i];
  for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
    $keyJ = $keys[$j];
    $diff = array_diff($data[$keyI], $data[$keyJ]);
    $data[$keyI] = $diff;
  }
}

print_r($data);
```